# Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row

Tags: python

```
StoredProc = """exec S_img @image_id =?"""
param = 12345
cursor.execute(StoredProc,param)
```

giving error as - Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row
tried below as well but

```
"""StoredProc = """exec S_img @image_id =%s"""
```

but still gives same error.

Answer (score 0):

"execute" function of the sqlite3 module only accepts an iterable parameter

Replace your line with this:

```
cursor.execute(StoredProc, (param, ))
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working